# How to read a html file from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, readfile

I'm trying to read a file using windows service but is giving as not found. As it does to read a file through my service?

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Email\Template.html");

string test = File.ReadAllText(filePath)
```

[Below where the file you want to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwFrC.png)

Comment: Hi Danielle, Is your issue is resolved!. If Yes, please share the answer with us. I am also facing the same issue. After installing and running my application I am unable to read the template file from the specified project path and i am getting error like file not exist(the reason is the setup project is not deploying our custom templates folder in the windows service installed path).

Answer (score 1):

1. right click on Template.html -> Properties
2. Copy to output directory -> Always Copy
3. and then get file path like this:

   var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "email\Template.html";

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "[Copy To Output Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2)" property is Enabled for this file.

[image]